# number of maps from [n] to [6], if there are conditions on at least how many elements must have each image?

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

For example, how many maps $f: [n] \to [6]$ are there, if at least one element must have image $2$ and at least $4$ different elements must have image $5$?

or in general: at least $a_i$ distinct elements must map to $i$ for $i = 1, ..., 6$

This could be done with the principle of inclusion and exclusion, but I need it for a computer programme, which already runs for too long, so I'm looking for an explicit formula, or something that's not a very long sum, if that's possible.

This is the same as the number of partitions of $[n]$ into $6$ parts, so I was thinking if it could be done with Stirling numbers, but I don't know how.

I was also thinking if I could do it with exponential generating functions, since we would get $\prod_{i=1}^6 (e^{x} - \frac{x^{a_i - 1}}{(a_i - 1)!} - \frac{x^{a_i - 2}}{(a_i - 2)!} - ... - 1)$, but I can't find an explicit formula.

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion doesn't seem so bad.  $6^n - 5^n - n5^{n-1}-\binom{n}{2}5^{n-2}-\binom{n}{3}5^{n-3}+4^n+n4^{n-1}+\binom{n}{2}4^{n-2}+\binom{n}{3}4^{n-3}$.  I don't expect a much cleaner answer.

Comment: Would this formula also be correct: $\sum_{d_i \geq a_i, d_1 + d_2+ d_3 + d_4 + d_5 + d_6 = n} \binom{n}{d_1, d_2, d_3, d_4, d_5, d_6}$